# Why is there no FileReader.read(String), when FileWriter has write(String)

Tags: java, io, filereader, filewriter

I have noticed that in [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) there is a method to write a String: [`.write(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29), whereas in [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) there is only [the possibility to read into a array of char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5B%5D%29).

Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: Well, how can the `Reader` guess how long a string you want to read?

Comment: @fge: It also does not know (or care) how many chars you want to read. It just fills part of the array, as much as is "convenient".

Comment: References are pass by value and a String is immutable so there is no way you could return something via a String argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String` class is immutable so it would be impossible to "read into a String". On the other hand, if you just meant `String read()`, then the problem there is that you haven't communicated the size of the string you wish to read. Yes, there could be a method `String read(int)`, which would say how much you want to read at once, but since the step from `char[]` to `String` is very simple, there was no need for a second method like that. `read(char[])`, on the other hand is a much more versatile – and efficient – method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can "upgrade" to BufferedReader,you get a `readLine` that does indeed return a String.

Answer (score 0):

In `FileWriter`, it is easy to write a `String`. However, in `FileReader`, there is no way to read a `String`, because it doesn't know when to stop. If it reads into a `char[]`, it can't read past the end of the array. If you want to read one line at a time, then create a `BufferedReader`, which has a method to read and return one line as a string. If you want to read a specific amount of characters into a string, you could write yourself a helper method:

```
public static String read(Reader in, int n) {
    char[] chars = new char[n];
    in.read(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's a good argument. The `char[]` also does not tell the method when to stop. Sure, it won't read more than fits in the array, but it is free to read less as well.

Comment: Yeah, if it hits EOF.

Comment: After looking at the API docs, the answer is yes. It also stops on an I/O error.

Comment: The code should use the return value to check how many chars were read. Have a look at the documentation for read(char[])

Comment: You must be reading a different set of API docs. "Read characters into an array. This method will block until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached." It is free to return "some input". Could be a single character.

Comment: That's the same API doc I read. Either you are right, or the API doc is too unclear to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, which is another way of saying that once you create a string you can't change it, for example to reuse the storage space it occupies. If there was a method in Reader that returned a string it would have to create a new string every time you call it, leading to the creation of a lot of garbage.

Also the semantics of such a method would not be clear: should it read as many characters as can be read without blocking, like the other read methods? That's probably not very useful. Should it read some sensible unit of text, like a line? That requires buffering, and should be the responsibility of a different class.